# ezDSP does not boot with programmed code

Tags: microcontroller, programming, dsp, ti-ccstudio, ezdsp

I have an ezDSP, and I can program the examples. They work just fine when I open the debugger. When I unplug the module and plug it back in, it always reverts back to the factory test code. How do I make it so that the module boots with my code, not the factory default?

Comment: I guess we're all just supposed to know what a "ezDSP" is?  It sounds like it's running from RAM and you have to get your code into flash somehow.

Comment: Not a real question and should be closed.

Comment: It most certainly is a real question, Leon. By ezDSP, I mean the TI ezDSP here http://focus.ti.com/docs/toolsw/folders/print/tmdx5505ezdsp.html

I suspect the same, that it is somehow putting the entire program into RAM. I was hoping that someone familiar with this module and has run into this problem would see my question and be able to answer it.

Comment: @Leon - no offense, but is that eternal exclamation mark necessary? It makes you look very self-righteous.

Comment: @some.hacker - why don't you attach that link to the term "ezDSP" in your question. The more information you give, the more users will be inclined to help.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do you get a program onto an eZdsp board?](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/3488/how-do-you-get-a-program-onto-an-ezdsp-board)

Comment: you should at least say which processor is on the board. i know you can get them with the TMS320F2808, but there could well be other 28xx variants.

Answer (score 1):

Here is TI's answer from their forums.

You need to burn your program to the SPI EEPROM of your eZdsp. For that, you need two things:

1) Create a boot image using the hex55 utility. You can get step-by-step instructions here:

http://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/C5000_Creating_Boot-Images

2) Use a programmer.out file to burn the image to SPI. The programmer can be found at

http://code.google.com/p/c5505-ezdsp/

under "C5505 EZDSP programming tool"

Load the program to your eZdsp using CCS, then input the file path to your boot image, and make sure it doesn't have any white spaces on the path or name of the file.

Comment: i believe it's flash, not eeprom, that stores code.

Comment: @JustJeff, Flash is a kind of [EEPROM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EEPROM). It is just so common we often refer to it differently and in some cases when purchasing there can be a difference. If you think about it, Flash is electronically erasable and reprogrammable.

Comment: @Kortuk - in these devices, at least the one I used, there's a great deal more flash than eeprom. The flash is only block erasable whereas eeprom is erasable on a byte-by-byte basis. And I'm not 100% sure at the moment, but I think the eeprom is attached by an SPI interface rather than on the processor bus like the flash. So underlying implementations aside, it's a distinction worth making in this case.

Comment: @JustJeff, I know many a person whom still says eeprom just including memories that last through power reset. I understand when you buy something that is being marketed as EEPROM it is going to be very different.

Answer (score 0):

Aren't there some dip switches on that board? The F2808 based one that I used had a bank of three switches that would control whether the cpu booted from flash or OTP or RAM.